# Modificar valor pasado a void

Tags: java

En mi clase principal creo una variable de tipo Date que quiero modificar mas tarde  en otra clase. Para ello cuando creo la nueva clase la llamo asi:

```
calendario=new VCalendario(fechaEntrada);
```

Pero en la clase VCalendario:

```
public VCalendario(Date _fechaADevolver)
{
    _fechaADevolver=new Date();
}
```

cuando intento asignarle un valor de la siguiente forma no puedo y Eclipse me indica el siguiente fallo:

```
Local variable _fechaADevolver defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
```

¿Como puedo modificarla?

Comment: Si no añades el código donde se produce un error de compilación no podremos ayudarte, pero tiene punta de que estás modificando una variable desde una función o clase anónima, que crea una *clausura*

Comment: Ya he modificado la pregunta con el codigo

Comment: Ese código no tiene mucho sentido, debería ser algo como `this._fechaADevolver = _fechaADevolver;`

Comment: Me parece que falta algo en tu código porque si bien esa asignación es solo visible dentro de ese método constructor (se pierde al terminar el método), por si sola no es una asignación inválida. Puede ser que estés usando esto dentro de otro objeto, un Runnable, u un Listener?

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como indica

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402493/local-variable-log-defined-in-an-enclosing-scope-must-be-final-or-effectively-fi

No puedes modificar la variable _fechaADevolver que es externa al constructor. Si es una variable y quieres modificarla deberás buscar otras opciones, el constructor no está pensado para este tipo de acciones, **el constructor está pensado para, entre otras cosas, inicialización de los atributos de clase a la hora de instanciar un objecto de dicha clase**.

Para **obtener/modificar los atributos** de clase tienes los **getters y setters** que tu mismo puedes definir. Algo así (tal y como apunta Pablo):

```
import java.util.Date;

public class MyClass {
    private Date fechaADevolver;

    public MyClass(Date fechaADevolver) {
        super();
        this.fechaADevolver = fechaADevolver;
    }

    /**
     * @return the fechaADevolver
     */
    public Date getFechaADevolver() {
        return fechaADevolver;
    }

    /**
     * @param fechaADevolver the fechaADevolver to set
     */
    public void setFechaADevolver(Date fechaADevolver) {
        this.fechaADevolver = fechaADevolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Como podria hacerlo, en dicha clase he creado un void que lo modifica pero tampoco asigna el valor correctamente :(

Comment: El constructor de la clase asignará el valor de los parámetros de entrada a los atributos de clase que tu hayas definido. Tienes que definir un atributo de clase con nombre fechaADevolver y de tipo Date e inicializarlo en el constructor. Edito mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Por el código que tienes si lo único que quieres es darle a tu fecha el valor de new Date() podrías ahorrarte toda la clase y simplemente en la clase donde operas con ella cuando te interese asignarle a tu variable el valor de new Date(), que creo que es lo que quieres hacer, si me equivoco corrígeme.

Un Saludo!